Changing primary color leads to multiple builds
I want to change the primary color on runtime. For this I use a Provider. When the color is changed, it changes with a transition with different shades, which leads to multiple builds, until final color is reached. My log from a single color change looks like this:

flutter: --> Changing primary color to Color(0xff43b0e6)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xffe54c44)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xffc75e62)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xffb86770)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xffaa707f)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xff9b798e)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xff8c829c)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xff7d8bab)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xff6f94b9)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xff609dc8)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xff51a6d7)
flutter: Build with primary color Color(0xff43b0e6)

I actually like the smooth transition effect, but in the app the color changes quite often, therefore I don't want to run into performance problems.
How can I achieve to build only once?
ThemeProvider
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode _themeMode;
  Color _primaryColor;

  ThemeProvider({required ThemeMode themeMode, required Color primaryColor})
      : _themeMode = themeMode,
        _primaryColor = primaryColor;

  ThemeMode get themeMode => _themeMode;
  Color get primaryColor => _primaryColor;

  set themeMode(ThemeMode themeMode) {
    if (themeMode != _themeMode) {
      _themeMode = themeMode;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  set primaryColor(Color primaryColor) {
    if (primaryColor != _primaryColor) {
      _primaryColor = primaryColor;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}

Main
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(themeMode: ThemeMode.light, primaryColor: Colors.red),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

MyApp
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport.global(
      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
        builder: (context, themeProvider, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Organizo',
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
            theme: buildLightTheme(themeProvider),
            darkTheme: buildDarkTheme(themeProvider),
            themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: const HomePage(),
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              S.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
            localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
              for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
                if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale?.languageCode) {
                  return supportedLocale;
                }
              }
              return const Locale('en');
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

HomePage
Color getRandomColor() {
  final random = Random();
  return Color.fromRGBO(
    random.nextInt(256),
    random.nextInt(256),
    random.nextInt(256),
    1,
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    print("Build with primary color ${context.theme.primaryColor}");
    return TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        foregroundColor: context.theme.primaryColor,
        backgroundColor: context.theme.primaryColor,
      ),
      onPressed: () async {
        var newColor = getRandomColor();
        print("--> Changing primary color to $newColor");
        themeProvider.primaryColor = newColor;
      },
      child: Text(
        "Change primary color",
        style: context.theme.textTheme.bodyMedium,
      ),
    );
  }
}

